# Powershell: Is there a programmatic way to determine is Notification is enabled on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, powershell

I wrote a script to send a notification in Windows 10 but it failed SILENTLY. Then I realised that the Notifications was turned off. But I can't seem to find if there is a command to check if Notification is turned on or off.

How do I programmatically check if the Notification is On or Off?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct way to check this using PowerShell,
But may be you can check registry value and get that value returned and go for if-else condition to fulfill your code.

Usually the value of  `ToastEnabled DWORD` located at
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PushNotifications` says the status of [PushNotifications](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4111-turn-off-notifications-apps-senders-windows-10-a.html)

> If ToastEnabled DWORD,

```
0 =  PushNotifications Turn off 
1 =  PushNotifications Turn on
```

Below code will help you to read , whether that value is 1 or 0.

```
$key = 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PushNotifications'
(Get-ItemProperty -Path $key -Name ToastEnabled).ToastEnabled
```

Also, if you wish you can check whether ["Action Center in Windows"](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/disable-action-center-windows-10/#:%7E:text=Turn%20off%20Action%20Center%20in%20Windows%2010%20Home%20or%20Pro&text=Go%20to%20Settings%20%3E%20System%20%3E%20Notifications,off%20or%20back%20on%20again.) has been disabled

```
$key2 = 'HKCU:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer'
(Get-ItemProperty -Path $key -Name DisableNotificationCenter).DisableNotificationCenter
```

Note `DisableNotificationCenter` is not a default key just like `ToastEnabled`. Someone has to manually create it. So if that has not been created, you will not see 0. Instead you may get

```
Get-ItemProperty : Property DisableNotificationCenter does not exist at path
```